# Access DoCmd.OpenReport loop to generate PDFs not properly picking up RecordSet data

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

I have an Access database that tracks the transactions of a specific type of account holders. Each account holder has a designated ID number. I have a query that lists all of the ID numbers of the account holders in the database. I also have a report that presents the transaction data of specific account holders. Each week a coworker of mine has to manually run the report for each account holder (about 80 in total) and export as a PDF, then send to each individual account holder via email.

The query that lists all account ID numbers is a select query 'qryIDdropdown' that presents two fields (columns): ID number and name of account holder. The report that is used to generate the PDF is called 'IDReport'. When the report is opened, an Enter Parameter Value box appears, in which the user types in the ID number.

I'm trying to execute a simple loop that grabs each unique ID number from the query 'qryIDdropdown' and enters it into the report, then saves as a PDF and loops to the next ID number.

I'm still relatively new to VBA and cannot figure out why my code is not working. When I run it, it saves the PDF files with the correct name and in the correct location, but it's just a copy of the same ID number report. Here's my code:

```
Sub pdfcreate()
Dim db As DAO.Database 
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim MyFileName As String
Dim mypath As String
Dim temp as String

mypath = "H:\TITLE_DEV\"

Set db = CurrentDb()

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [ID Number] FROM [qryIDdropdown]")
rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF

    temp = rs("ID Number")
    MyFileName = rs("ID Number") & ".PDF"

    DoCmd.OpenReport "IDReport", acViewReport, "ID Number = '" & temp & "'"

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "IDReport"
    DoEvents

    rs.MoveNext
Loop


rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I step through I can see that my *temp* string is equal to the correct (unique each loop) ID Number, but the report is run as though the same ID number is being entered each time.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: is id numeric or text?

Comment: the id is numeric

Comment: i dont think you need the `'`'s then in the id number =

Comment: i removed the apostrophes so it now reads

`DoCmd.OpenReport "IDReport", acViewReport, "ID Number = " & temp`

and it is still doing the same thing

Comment: I found a working solution on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641551/using-ms-access-macro-or-vba-loop-to-print-individual-reports?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you launch the report manually, do you get any input prompts? You should not and you do NOT want this occuring.

Your code looks near ok, but the "where" clause is the 3rd parameter of the OpenReport. So you should have this:

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport "IDReport", acViewReport,, "ID Number = '" & temp & "'"
```

Also, a space in a column name is a REAL bad no no! So, above needs to be this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "IDReport", acViewReport,, "[ID Number] = '" & temp & "'"
```

So, any column with spaces needs to be surrounded by [] else a column called ORDER BY???? - is that a sql order by clause, or a column name? SQL can't determine what follows a space in additional SQL commands, or even a column name - so use [] around any column with a space in it.

Next up?

Is the [ID Number] column a text data type, or is it an actual NUMBER column? If it is an actual number column, then you don't surround the criteria with ' or " (single or double quotes).

So, change the condition to the "where" clause - do NOT use the filter option.
Add [] around any column with spaces - this applies to darn near every variant of SQL out on the planet.

So, check if the ID Number is text or actual number column - if a true number data type, then remove the code to surround the value without quotes.
eg:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "IDReport", acViewReport,, "[ID Number] = " & temp
```