# Saving Report by individual page

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following VBA code that prints out to PDF all receipts in my MS Access database. How can I modify the code to:

a) Filter the printouts by a specific date range?
b) Save each receipt individually (by page)?

```
Private Sub PrintAllRCPTSBtn_Click()

    Dim reportName As String
    Dim outputPath As String
    Dim serialNumber As Long
    
    ' Set the name of the report to export
    reportName = "ReceiptR"
    
    ' Retrieve the serial number from the table/query
    serialNumber = DLookup("ReceiptID", "ReceiptT")
    
    ' Set the output path for the PDF file
    outputPath = "C:\Desktop\Trial Receipt Dump VBA\" & "AllRCPTS" & ".pdf"
    
    ' Export the report to PDF format
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, acFormatPDF, outputPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Several ways to go about this. 1) in loop open report filtered to single record, OutPutTo PDF, close report, repeat or 2) set printer to MS PDF Printer and in loop use PrintOut methed to print 1 page at a time or 3) OutPutTo to a single PDF then split up the PDF to individual PDF files.

Comment: Highly appreciated and will test the options. But how can I add a prompt for the date range of the receipts that I need printed?

Comment: Have user input dates into textboxes or comboboxes on a form.

Comment: @June7, many thanks once again. I have developed the code to filter for a given date range, but cant seem to come with a loop and split sequence.

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Reports(reportName).Pages

        Dim pdfPath As String
        pdfPath = folderPath & "RCPT " & ReceiptID & " - " & CoopCode & MemberID & " - " & Notes & " - Page " & i & ".pdf"
        
        Reports(reportName).Page = i
        
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, acFormatPDF, pdfPath
        
        DoEvents
    Next i

Comment: If you are trying option 1, then need to: a) DoCmd.OpenReport with filter criteria b) DoCmd.OutPutTo c) DoCmd.Close d) repeat. This usually involves opening a recordset and looping its records to pull record ID for use by DoCmd.OpenReport. Did you review the SO question referenced in closing your question? Here's another which may have better example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641551/using-ms-access-macro-or-vba-loop-to-print-individual-reports. Use date range criteria to filter recordset.

Comment: @June7, it appears I have another challenge. I am using a btn to run the code from the form where I enter my Receipt Data. However, the naming convention for the combined pdf turns out to be for which ever record I entering at the time. Any suggestion? I am checking on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641551/using-ms-access-macro-or-vba-loop-to-print-individual-reports to see if I can replicate this and will let you know